# Processing the canvas after loading objects using loadFromJSON() method

Tags: fabricjs

I want to copy the content of one canvas to another then to process the second canvas and to save the canvas as png image, but when i copied to the second canvas, Images are not showing in the png exported using `canvas.toDataURL("png")` method. All images are located in the same server, also these images are visible in the canvas but not in the Image exported.
Why is it so ?

**Code Updated :**

```
copyCanvas.clear();
console.log(case_canvas.toJSON());
copyCanvas.loadFromJSON(case_canvas.toJSON(), function(o, object) {
//console.log(o);
});
copyCanvas.calcOffset();
    //copyCanvas.overlayImage = null;
    //copyCanvas.renderAll();
console.log(copyCanvas.toJSON());
window.open(copyCanvas.toDataURL("png"));
```

All items except images from the canvas are exported and can be seen in the new window,

Thanks for any help.

Comment: please show the code you are using (trimmed and formatted for readability)

Comment: any reason you're using JSON serialisation instead of copying the image data use getImageData/putImageData?

Answer (score 2):

After loading json to canvas you have to call `canvas.renderAll()` in the callback of `canvas.loadFromJSON` - and all other stuff.

```
copyCanvas.loadFromJSON(case_canvas.toJSON(), function() {
  copyCanvas.renderAll();
  copyCanvas.calcOffset();
  console.log(copyCanvas.toJSON());
  window.open(copyCanvas.toDataURL("png"));
});
```

The callback is raised after all objects (including images) are loaded. fabric.Image objects are async - that's why image objects are missing.